# Apache Ignite installation from termius

Tags: ignite, termius

I have a syntax error in running Apache Ignite in Termius, Can anyone help me with that?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaKEP.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could paste the error message text as text rather than a screenshot.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].